The transaction tag is too unspecific. Should we split it up?
transactions is on a huge number of questions. Transactions are such a central element of Bitcoin that it would make sense to better structure those questions. We had a similar issue with mining. Which was burninated earlier this year.
Would it make sense to split up transactions? Which existing and new tags would be valuable in replacing it?

Please propose one tag per answer, and add support by describing what topic it would collect. Please upvote answers that you find useful, and downvote tags that you don’t. Use comments on answers to discuss viability or edit the answers directly to improve them.
Once we have concluded this discussion, another post will follow to suggest how to implement it and what to watch for while retagging transactions.

coinbase-transaction
The "coinbase transaction" is the transaction inside a block that pays the miner his block reward.
Use this tag when asking questions referring only to the coinbase transaction.

transaction-malleability
A property of Bitcoin transactions that allows them to be replicated with another transaction id before they are included in a block.

confirmations
Confirmations correspond to the number of blocks that are dependent on a given transaction. This includes the block containing that transaction and all blocks after it in the blockchain. The more confirmations a transaction has, the more likely is it that it will remain in the blockchain permanently.
Use this tag instead of transactions when a question asks about the nature of confirmations, how transactions gain confirmations, or deals the number of confirmations a transaction has.

utxo
Unspent transaction outputs are created by transactions and allow the owner of an associated address to spent a specific amount.
Use when the topic is about spendable balances.

transaction-fees
Related to transaction fees in the Bitcoin network.
Use this tag when asking about how transaction fees work. For questions that ask about discovering the right amount of fees use fee-estimation. For questions that relate to the mechanics that drive fee levels use fee-market.

fee-estimation
Questions about deriving the right amount of fees to add to your transaction.
Use this tag when requesting guidance about implementing fee-estimation or asking questions about current approaches of fee-estimation.

multi-sig-transactions
With multi-signature transactions you can add up to 3 different bitcoin addresses as recipients. In order to be able to spend the funds, approval is required from a chosen number of those recipients.
Use this tag when inquiring about m-of-n transactions and other multisignature schemes.

We also have [tag:multi-sig] and [tag:multi-sig-address]. Perhaps those three tags could be combined to one tag?

raw-transaction
Raw transactions are bitcoin transactions that have been serialized for network transmission, or for use in Bitcoin Core's RPC interface.
Use this tag for questions about crafting your own transactions without relying on a wallet.

unconfirmed-transactions
Transactions that have not been included in a block yet.
The inevitable tag for stuck transactions, transactions that spend unconfirmed outputs, transactions without fees, and other lost brethren.

Not sure we need a tag for 0-confirmations and unconfirmed-transactions. Also, it might be good to put all these in that one larger answer and delete the individual answers.

@StephenM347: Zero-Confirmation deals with accepting transactions before they are confirmed for which a whole industry branch has sprung up, while unconfirmed transactions refers to stuck transactions. I'd say they have distinct focuses. Although I agree that we could merge quite a few of the almost 90 "unconfirmed-transactions" questions.

0-confirmation
Collects questions concerned with the practice of accepting transactions before they reach their first confirmation, i.e. "zero-confirmation".

transaction-verification
Refers to the process of checking the validity of transactions.

Sorry, I realized that the number of answers were exploding, so I'm rather collecting my remaining proposals here. For discussion feel free to add more answer posts.
transaction-selection – Questions about what criteria influence the selection of unconfirmed transactions for block inclusion.
transaction-id – The unique identifier of a transaction corresponding to the sha256d hash of the transaction.
non-standard-transaction – Transactions which deviate from the standard transactions created by BitcoinCore yet are valid. Non-standard transactions can have other redemption scripts than transactions to a public key, e.g. redeemable by password, multi-signature, any signature, checking external states, and more.
reverse-transaction – Questions relating to how particular transactions can be undone or replaced.
transaction-propagation – Questions about the manner, speed and incentives of relaying transactions in the Bitcoin network.
transaction-input – Questions about the mechanics of redeeming a UTXO in an input script.
offline-transactions – Questions about transmitting bitcoins without the wallet being connected to the Bitcoin network.
script – Within the context of Bitcoin, scripts are a set of instructions on how to complete a transaction. The default send/receive actions are scripts but the protocol can be extended through the creation of new scripts, such as the DNS replacement abilities of NameCoin.
output ← This still needs a wiki excerpt, perhaps should be merged into another tag.
mempool ← Needs a wiki excerpt.

non-standard transaction tag is somewhat vague. Does a standard transaction refer to a transaction that passes the IsStandard test in Core? Otherwise, a standard transaction is not properly defined as per the Bitcoin Specification.

@renlord: Yeah, I guess it is a tag that applies only to questions about general behavior of transactions that don't pass the "isStandard()". Maybe that's one to axe.
